# How to detect if iCloud account on a device changed?

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, icloud, user-accounts

How to detect if iCloud account being used on a device changed?

A user signs out from **Settings > iCloud** and another user signs in his/her account.

How to detect this change when the app is opened?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Just add an observer for the notification with name `NSUbiquityIdentityDidChangeNotification`

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
    addObserver: self
       selector: @selector (iCloudAccountAvailabilityChanged:)
           name: NSUbiquityIdentityDidChangeNotification
         object: nil];
```

> If a user signs out of iCloud, such as by turning off Documents & Data
>   in Settings, the ubiquityIdentityToken method returns nil. To enable
>   your app to detect when a user signs out and signs back in, register
>   for changes in iCloud account availability. - ***Apple Documentation***

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/General/Conceptual/iCloudDesignGuide/Chapters/iCloudFundametals.html

Comment: I just can't believe that I couldn't find ubiquityIdentityToken in ref docs. Thank you very much.

Comment: The user could also log out or back in while your app is not running. You should save the value of the ubiquity token somewhere and, when your app launches, compare the current value to the previously saved value.